What is the difference between Main Antenna and Rx-diversity antenna
I am using Quectel SC200 in my design .Below is the description of it's antenna interface.
SC200E-CE/-EM/-NA and SC206E-EM/-NA provide four antenna interfaces for the main, Rx-diversity,Wi-Fi/Bluetooth, and GNSS antennas respectively.
I understood all the other antenna specifications except main, Rx-diversity antenna.
May I know the difference between main antenna and Rx-diversity antenna and it's use.

The Main and Rx-Diversity antenna interfaces are both used for cellular radio communication in a MIMO (multiple-input multiple-output) configuration. They should each be connected to an antenna that supports the LTE frequency bands (see data sheet). To the extent possible, the antennas should be separated in space, and again if possible, polarized differently.
A single radio propagation channel is subject to fading effects caused by multipath reflections, antenna pattern irregularities, and other factors. While a second (diversity) channel may also be subject to its own fading effects, they may not the same as (i.e. correlated with) the first channel's fading. In basic diversity reception systems, the receiver can switch between the antennas to pick the best signal. Your modem is more sophisticated and can combine the two signals to enhance their strength, or even receive on two channels simultaneously to achieve faster speeds.

The automotive application needs two SIMs. SIM1 = main antenna SIM2 = Diversity.
In your case RX - Diversity is used as receiver
